# Cannot Run Play Framework Project on Netbeans 7.2 IDE

Tags: java, playframework, netbeans-7, playframework-1.x

I have a working Play Framework project. I'm using Play Framework version number **1.2.5** and Java version **1.7 update 5**. I have been used `play netbeansify` command on terminal and successfully load the project.

But then, when I tried to run the project its failed to RUN and Netbeans console show error like this:

```
C:\play-1.2.5\id doesn't exist
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8099
Error: Could not find or load main class ${jvm.memory}
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)
```

I have tried to replace Play Framework version number **1.2.5** to **1.2.4** and I use `play netbeansify` command again. Then, when I tried running the project, its RUNNING.

Is Netbeans 7.2 IDE doesn't support Play Framework version number **1.2.5**? Or I forgot the step to import project in Netbeans?

**-- EDIT 1**

For specification detail I'm using Windows 7 32-bit Operating System, Java 7 update 5 32-bit version, and Netbeans 7.2 32-bit version.

Comment: Have you tried using play! 2 ? Do you get the same error ?

Comment: My project doesn't use Play Framework version number 2.x because the requirement of the project is using Play Framework version number 1.x. Have you check using Netbeans IDE 7.2 and Play Framework version number 1.2.5 to run Play Framework project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to the application.conf file:

```
jvm.memory=-Xmx256M -Xms32M
```

You can tune to your liking, but this should be a basic setting.

Matt

Comment: Thanks Matt, you inspired me. But, I don't know why only one parameter such as -Xmx works on my computer. Have to try using your configuration wasn't work. And I tried to use only one parameter such as -Xmx256M, then it WORKS.

Comment: I got the same problem and your solution help me fixed it. However, let make it clear, try "jvm.memory=-Xmx256M" or "jvm.memory=-Xmx32M".

Answer (score 0):

I'm running on 1.2.2. When change from Netbeans 7.1.1 to 7.2, there's no problem. I even don't have to do any additional step, just install Netbeans 7.2, it will automatically import 7.1.1 configurations, then hit RUN and it works.

Have not tried the play!framework 1.2.5 yet.

Comment: I haven't used Netbeans 7.1.1 and the previous version I have is Netbeans 6.9. I also didn't import the previous version configurations. You may try to user Play!Framework version number 1.2.5. Is the same problem occured?