# play project fail to run in the Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, playframework

this question is similiar to another question(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11683802/cannot-run-play-framework-project-on-netbeans-7-2-ide)

When I use play-1.2.5, my project fail to run in Netbeans 7.
But when I change the play version to 1.2.4,it run success.

Here is the Exception when I run the project in netbenas 7 with play-1.2.5 framework

```
E:\play-1.2.5\id doesn't exist
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ${jvm/memory}
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ${jvm.memory}
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: ${jvm.memory}.  Program will exit.
Exception in thread "main" Java Result: 1
```

Comment: problem is clear with the exception trace,    `Could not find the main class` find the reason.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your application.conf

jvm.memory=-Xmx256M

Answer (score -1):

Try increasing the heap size for the JVM.

Comment: The key is ${jvm/memory} I searched for this, and it looks like when you see an error like this, that it means that the JVM could not allocate enough heap during class loading, but somehow that is masked as a NoClassDefFoundError.